# Doubly Linked List returning null at the end of list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list, and I am testing it with an iterator. For some reason the dll returns null at the end of the list and I can't figure out why. I would greatly appreciate an expert eye to spot what I am missing. Thanks in advance

test:

```
    void testIterator() {
        DoublyLinkedList<Integer> ll = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) ll.addLast(i);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> buf = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer i : ll) {
            buf.add(i);
        }
        assertEquals("[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", buf.toString());
    }
```

The test returns:
expecting [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] but was [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,null]

The Doubly Linked List

````
import java.util.Iterator;


public class DoublyLinkedList<E> implements List<E> {
    /** Sentinel node at the beginning of the list */
    private Node<E> header;                    // header sentinel

    /** Sentinel node at the end of the list */
    private Node<E> trailer;                   // trailer sentinel

    /** Number of elements in the list (not including sentinels) */
    private int size = 0; 
    //---------------- nested Node class ----------------
    /**
     * Node of a doubly linked list, which stores a reference to its
     * element and to both the previous and next node in the list.
     */

    private static class Node<E> {
        private E data;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> previous; 

        public Node(E data, Node<E> previous,Node<E> next)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
        public E getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }
        public Node<E> getPrevious()
        {
            return previous;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> n)
        {
            next = n;
        }
        public void setPrevious(Node<E> p)
        {
            previous = p;
        }
        public void setData(E d)
        {
            data = d;
        }
    } //----------- end of nested Node class -----------

    // instance variables of the DoublyLinkedList
    // number of elements in the list

    /** Constructs a new empty list. */
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);
        header.setNext(trailer);
    }

    // public accessor methods
    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the linked list.
     * @return number of elements in the linked list
     */
    public int size() { return size; }

    /**
     * Tests whether the linked list is empty.
     * @return true if the linked list is empty, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() { return size == 0; }

    @Override
    public E get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if((i>size()-1) || isEmpty()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("It is not possible to get this indexed value");
        }
        Node<E> current = header.getNext();
        for(int j=0;j<i && current != trailer;j++) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return current.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int i, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Node<E> current = header.getNext();
        if (isEmpty() || i > size()-1)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete either index too big or list is empty");
        }
        for(int j =0; j<i;j++) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setData(e);
        return current.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int i, E e) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (i < 0|| i > size()-1)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete either index too big or list is empty");
        }
        else {
            Node<E> current = header.getNext();
            for(int j = 0; j< i;j++) {
                current = current.getNext();    
            }
            addBetween(e,current.getPrevious(),current);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (isEmpty() || i > size()-1)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot delete either index too big or list is empty");
        }
        Node<E> current = header.getNext();
        Node<E> previous = header;

        //find the correct node to remove
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        Node<E> next =current.getNext();
                previous.setNext(next);
        next.setPrevious(previous);
        size--;
        return current.getData();

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
    }
    private class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements Iterator<E> {
        private Node<E> current;
        public DoublyLinkedListIterator() {
            current = header.getNext();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if(!hasNext()) throw new RuntimeException("No such element");

            E res = current.getData();
            current = current.getNext();
            return res;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns (but does not remove) the first element of the list.
     * @return element at the front of the list (or null if empty)
     */
    public E first() {
        // TODO
        return header.getNext().getData();
    }

    /**
     * Returns (but does not remove) the last element of the list.
     * @return element at the end of the list (or null if empty)
     */
    public E last() {
        // TODO
        return trailer.getPrevious().getData();
    }

    // public update methods
    /**
     * Adds an element to the front of the list.
     * @param e   the new element to add
     */
    public void addFirst(E e) {
        addBetween(e,header,header.getNext());
    }

    /**
     * Adds an element to the end of the list.
     * @param e   the new element to add
     */
    public void addLast(E e) {
        addBetween(e,trailer.getPrevious(),trailer);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the first element of the list.
     * @return the removed element (or null if empty)
     */
    public E removeFirst() {
        Node<E> current = header.getNext();
        remove(0);
        return current.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the last element of the list.
     * @return the removed element (or null if empty)
     */
    public E removeLast() {
        return remove((this.size()-1));
    }

    // private update methods
    /**
     * Adds an element to the linked list in between the given nodes.
     * The given predecessor and successor should be neighboring each
     * other prior to the call.
     *
     * @param predecessor   node just before the location where the new element is inserted
     * @param successor     node just after the location where the new element is inserted
     */
    private void addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node(e,predecessor,successor);
        predecessor.setNext(newNode);
        successor.setPrevious(newNode);
        this.size++;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given node from the list and returns its element.
     * @param node    the node to be removed (must not be a sentinel)
     */

    /**
     * Produces a string representation of the contents of the list.
     * This exists for debugging purposes only.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("[");

        Node<E> current = header.getNext();

        while (current.getNext() != null && current != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(current.getData());
            stringBuilder.append(", ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        stringBuilder.replace(stringBuilder.length()-2, stringBuilder.length(), "");
        stringBuilder.append("]");

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //ArrayList<String> all;
        //LinkedList<String> ll;
        DoublyLinkedList<String> ll = new DoublyLinkedList<String>();

        String[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");

        for (String s : alphabet) {
            ll.addFirst(s);
            ll.addLast(s);
        }
        System.out.println(ll.toString());

        for (String s : ll) {
            System.out.print(s + ", ");
        }
    }
} //----------- end of DoublyLinkedList class -----------```
````

Comment: You have a `trailer` in your list with a value of `null`, why? And if you go that way, make sure your `iterator` remembers that in its `hasNext` method

Comment: `while (current.getNext() != null && current != null)` this line should throw an exception is a null was to be `current`